# "Body requirements not met" when passing a req to a method in c++ (Boost Beast library)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-beast

I am trying to pass a req to a method. My code is:

```
void handle_request(boost::beast::string_view doc_root, http::request<http::string_body> req, Send send)
{
   some code here
}
```

but when I try to compile it, I am getting this error:

```
  "Body requirements not met"
```

How can I fix it?

The error doesn't come from these lines, but if I remove the function definition from code, it doesn't show any error.

There are several other errors tat all comes from

```
beast\http\message.hpp.
```

Comment: What line gives that error?

Comment: @NathanOliver Please see updated question.

Comment: If you comment all the code in the function do you still get the error?  Looks like you are getting a `static_assert` fired.  We need to figure out what line is causing the assert to fire.

Comment: Do the unmodified examples compile for you?

Comment: @VinnieFalco The unmodified code works for me

Comment: Can we see the complete declaration for your Body type?

Answer (score 0):

The message is a likely result of the `is_body` concept check.

The code you showed cannot cause the error, as this snippet demonstrates:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a796136e5895494)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http/type_traits.hpp>

int main() {
    using namespace boost::beast;

    http::request<http::string_body> req;

    static_assert(http::is_body<http::string_body>::value, "all good");
}
```

If that doesn't compile for you then either your Boost sources have become corrupt or your compiler is very misguided.

More likely is that you didn't mention code that actually triggers the error, or that you are not compiling the code that you see in the editor.

Comment: How can I find which line of my code generate the error?

Comment: Most compilers emit messages saying where template instantiations arise from ("required from"....). Look for the first one that points to one of your source files.